# Does there exist an entire function $h$ such that $p, q, r$ are the constant multiplies of $h$?

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

Let $p, q, r$ be non-vanishing non-constant entire holomorphic functions such that $$p+q+r = 0$$
Does there exist an entire function $h$ such that $p, q, r$ are the constant multiplies of $h$?

Comment: I see no ways, how does this particular question can be improved. I guess that providing unneccesary, in this case, even doubtful thoughts would cause incoherence and misunderstanding by those, who attempt to get into the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $r$ doesn't vanish, then $p/r$ and $q/r$ are entire and don't vanish.

We have that $p/r+q/r=-1$. By [Picard's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem) either $q/r$ is constant or there is a point in which $q/r=-1$, since $q/r$ already skips the value $0$ and it can't skip yet another one. At that point $p/r$ would vanish, which is a contradiction. Therefore $q/r$ is constant and therefore so is $p/r$. Take $h:=r$. Then $p=(p/r)h$, $p=(q/r)h$, and $r=1h$.